# How to efficiently select a redux store slice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, reselect

In a React/Hooks/ReduxToolkit application, what are the efficiency implications of selecting a slice of the redux store in the following two methods:

Store Structure:

const store: RootState = {
students,
courses,
}

`students` is a dictionary of students indexed by their `id` ... i.e.
students: [id: number]: Student
Similarly, `courses` is a dictionary of courses indexed by their `id`

In a component that is only concerned with rendering `student` information, what are the performance implication of directly selecting for the relevant slice in the component versus creating a memoized selector that the component then invokes?

Case 1 (direct selecting of slice in component):

```js
const StudentReactComponent = () => {
const allStudents = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.students)

...
return some render logic that makes use of `allStudents`
...
}
```

Case 2 (selecting a slice via a memoized selector):

```js
// This memoized selector would actually be imported from a `studentSelectors`
// module instead of being declared above the react component
const selectStudentsDictionary = createSelector((state: RootState) => state.students, students => students)

const StudentReactComponent = () => {
const allStudents = useSelector(selectStudentsDictionary)
...
return some render logic that makes use of `allStudents`
...
```

Comment: Since you are straight up accessing the data in both cases, the first case would actually be quicker. If though you are not generating a new function on every render, you are comparing the objects on the selector and storing the result. Instead of just straight up accessing the data. So go for case one here. For more infos: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`useSelector` forces a component to re-render when the selector returns a new reference that is different than the previous reference: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates .  So, as written, the component will re-render whenever `state.students` changes.

The "memoized" selector in this example is actually useless. Memoization only matters when you have *derived* data.  Any time you have a `createSelector` instance that just has `x => x` as its "output selector", you're using `createSelector` the wrong way, and this could likely just be a plain function.

As a related side note, I am actually planning to write a new "Selectors and Memoization" usage guide page for the Redux core docs in the near future.  Until then, I'd suggest reading through my post [Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/).  It's a few years old, but still mostly relevant here.